# Is it possible to have a title with a mimetype other than HTML?

Tags: php, mime-types, title

I'm looking for ideas to title a text/plain output so it's easier to find in a user's browser history. The only way I can think of accomplishing this is with an iframe. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print the content using `htmlentities()`, so that all the HTML tags will be shown verbatim:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Your title</title>
</head>
<body><pre><?php echo htmlentities($text); ?></pre></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text file in `<html><body><pre>` and `</pre><body></html>` and transmit it as `text/html`. Then you can squeeze in a `<head><title>Title</title></head>` at the appropriate place.